# "TypeError: 'int' object is not callable" in text adventure game

Tags: python, typeerror

I am writing a text adventure game for my History class. I'm still pretty new to Python, so please bear with me.

```
# Massachusetts Text Adventure
#
#      Written by Nick Decker
#
#            In Python 3.6.2

import time
from random import *

startgame = False
food=100
drink=100
morale=80
people=64
health=80
week=1
start=5

def week():
    global week
    global food
    global drink
    global morale
    global people
    global health
    global start
    print ("\n" * 100)
    print("Week number",week)
    print("Food left: ",food)
    print("Drink left: ",drink)
    print("Morale: ",morale)
    print("People alive: ",people)
    ftp = input("How much food will you feed your people? Choose a number between 0-10.")
    if ftp==0:
        print("You did not feed your people.")
        health = health - 5
        morale = morale - 10
    elif ftp <= 5 and ftp != 0:
        print("You gave your people some food.")
        health = health - 2
        food = food - ftp
        morale = morale - 2
    elif ftp <= 10 and ftp > 5:
        print("You gave your people a lot of food.")
        health = health + 2
        food = food - ftp
        morale = morale + 2
    dtp = input("How much water will you give your people? Choose a number between 0-10.")
    if dtp==0:
        print("You did not give your people any water")
        health = health - 10
        morale = morale - 10
    elif dtp <=5 and dtp != 0:
        print ("You gave your people some water.")
        health = health + 1
        morale = morale + 5
        drink = drink - dtp
    elif dtp > 5 and dtp <= 10:
        print("You gave your people a lot of water")
        health = health + 5
        morale = morale + 5
        drink = drink - dtp

    if health <= 70:
        dead = randint(1,7)
        people = people - dead

    if morale <= 65:
        com = randint(1,100)
        if com <= 50:
            morale = morale
        elif com > 50 and com <= 100:
            mutiny()
    week = week + 1
    whattodo()

def whattodo():
    if week > 8:
        print("You've made it to the New World!")
        win = input("To play again, type RESTART. To quit, type QUIT.")
        if win==RESTART:
            story()
        elif win==QUIT:
            quit()
    else:
        week()

def background():
    global start
    print ("\n" * 100)
    print("Congratulations! You have been appointed by the King himself to lead a journey to Massachusetts!")
    time.sleep(2.0)
    print("You are leading a fleet of 11 ships, though in this game, you will be in charge of only one. This ship's name is the Arbella.")
    time.sleep(2.0)
    print("The voyage will take months, and you have to keep the people alive and happy.")
    time.sleep(2.0)
    print("By controlling food and drink you can keep your people alive.")
    time.sleep(2.0)
    print("Good luck!")
    time.sleep(5.0)
    start=0
    week()

def story():
    global startgame
    global food
    global drink
    global morale
    global health
    global people
    global week
    global start

    startgame = True
    food=100
    drink=100
    morale=80
    people=64
    health=80
    week=1

    print ("\n" * 100)
    print('Welcome to the Massachusetts Text Adventure!')
    time.sleep(2.0)
    print('In this game you are on your way to the New World as John Winthrop.')
    time.sleep(2.0)
    print('Along the way, you will face many dangers.')
    time.sleep(2.0)
    print('You will make friends...')
    time.sleep(2.0)
    print('... and enemies.')
    time.sleep(5.0)
    background()

def mutiny():
    print ("\n" * 100)
    global morale
    print("The people on your ship are unhappy! They are planning a mutiny!")
    time.sleep(2.0)
    print("The mutiny has a 50/50 chance of being succesfull.")
    ms = randint(1,100)
    if ms <= 50:
        print("The mutiny failed, and the crew's morale has been boosted by 15!")
        morale = morale + 15
        whattodo()
    elif ms > 50 and ms <= 100:
        fail = input("You've failed! Type RESTART to restart. Type QUIT to quit.")
        if fail==RESTART:
            story()
        elif fail==QUIT:
            quit()

while startgame==False:
    story()
```

When I run the program, it continues until calling upon week() in background(). It then gives me these errors:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "E:\MassTA.py", line 154, in <module>
    story()
  File "E:\MassTA.py", line 133, in story
    background()
  File "E:\MassTA.py", line 102, in background
    week()
TypeError: 'int' object is not callable
```

Again, I'm still pretty new, so I'm sorry if it's a mess.
Could someone please tell me how to fix these errors?
Thanks!

Comment: You have both a global `week` variable and a function. Change one of them to something else.

Comment: Hello, and welcome to Stack Overflow! When posting code, try to reduce your code to an [MCVE] ; meaning, try to re-create your problem with the least amount of code. Since we didn't write your code, we don't know all of the nuances or intentions of each line, so we don't know what is important and what isn't, but you do. Simplifying the code you post will help us help you by making locating the code's errors easier. In this case, the problem with the `week` variable was right near the top and quick to find, but in the future errors might not be so simple, so try to get in the habit of [MCVE]s

Answer (score 2, accepted):

At the beginning of your program you have variable week assigned as an int: week = 1. That is being confused with your function: week(). rename the integer or the functions to correct your issue.